# Run /etc/cron.daily/apt at a specific time (i.e. without anacron)

Tags: apt, cron

I want to setup a cron job to download up-to-date package only at night. But I found that the *cron.daily* jobs will be run by *anacron* if it's installed, so if my computer fails to wake-up at night to do the job, it will run the next time I turn it on.

How configure my system to run `/etc/cron.daily/apt` exclusively with *cron* (i.e. at and only at the specified time)?

This is my `/etc/crontab`

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Answer (score 4):

Move your script out of `/etc/cron.daily` and add an entry for it directly in `/etc/crontab`. For example, you could move it to `/usr/local/sbin/cron-apt` and then add this entry to `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 5 * * * root /usr/local/sbin/cron-apt
```

This will give you fine control of the exact timing of your job as well. The command `man 5 crontab` will give you more information on the crontab format.

Comment: /etc/cron.d exists...

Comment: According to [cron(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/cron.8.html): "In general, the system administrator should not use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab".

Comment: I'd like to know the rationale for this, because it doesn't make much or any sense.  So, I ignore it (and it says "should" anyway).